# Telnetlib not reading the whole O/P from router

Tags: python-3.x, telnetlib

I executed the below code, and the file generated by the code doesn't have the whole O/P. The command when executed on the same router has lot of data. Is there any buffer size issue concerning over here. 
from telnetlib import *

```
host = 'route-views3.routeviews.org'
conn = Telnet(host)
conn.write(("sh ip bgp 64.57.28.241/12 longerprefixes\n").encode('ascii'))
conn.write(("exit\n").encode('ascii'))
x = conn.read_all().decode("utf-8")
conn.close()
fo = open('sample.txt', 'w')
fo.write(x)
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the 'exit' command is causing the router to drop its end of the connection before all the buffered output from the previous command has been sent to the network.  A simple delay (`time.sleep(1)`, perhaps) before the 'exit' would probably fix this.  Or, you could use `conn.read_until()` before sending 'exit', passing it a string that won't be seen until the very end of the command output (the router's command line prompt, perhaps).

Comment: so what argument should be passed for conn.read_until() in order to wait untill whole O/P is dispalyed.

Comment: How would I know?  YOU'RE the one who's actually seen the output of the command.

Comment: ok, i'll adjust it. when i changed to code to fo.write(conn.read_all().decode("utf-8")) and removed the variable "x" , its not writing in the file. Is it a wrong method to write in a file.

Comment: How did you manage to misinterpret my answer as telling you to do that?  Obviously, you need to do the connection read *before* you close the connection.  If you want to keep the file writing at the bottom, you're still going to need a variable like `x` to hold the read data until that time.

Comment: no, i didnt misinterpret your answer. i was trying to do some changes to code. I closed the connection after fo.close(),still my file is empty.